# Can I save an Aloe barberae tree with a split in the trunk?

Tags: trees, aloe, damage

Today I purchased an [Aloe barberae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_barberae) tree from the nursery. During the time it was delivered to my home it split itself on the trunk where it has two branches. The split is approximately 120 mm (just under 5 inches) long and about 5 mm (1/4 inch) wide.

I have tied both branches together with rope to close the split and removed some of the lower leaves to make the branches lighter.

I'm just wondering if this plant will heal itself in time, and if there's anything more I can do to ensure that it has the best chance of healing itself.

---

Here are a couple of photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use the [edit] link underneath your post to add new information to it. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tying the branches together with a string is the only way to save it. It will either work or it will not, but you did the right thing. Cotton is the best material for this treatment.